# Deploying pre-encrypted configuration files to a production environment

Tags: asp.net, .net, encryption, web-config, aspnet-regiis.exe

We want to encrypt all our web app configuration files that we deploy to a server. We'd prefer to do this as a step in our build process and include the pre-encrypted files inside the MSI.

This means that our build server (encryptor) and production server (decryptor) need the same keys. So I'm trying to do a very basic test for now. Encrypt a Web.Config on MachineA - Decrypt it on MachineB. Here's what I've tried to test so far

Create a new RSA Key Pair Container on my local pc.

```
aspnet_regiis -pc "MyContainer" -exp
```

Give ACL Permissions to me & the NetworkService users.

```
aspnet_regiis -pa "MyContainer" "MyDomain\My.Account"
aspnet_regiis -pa "MyContainer" "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
```

Export that key pair to an xml file

```
aspnet_regiis -px "MyContainer" C:\MyContainer.xml -pri
```

Copy that file to another pc & import it

```
aspnet_regiis -pi "MyContainer" C:\MyContainer.xml
```

Give my colleague & his machines NetworkService user permissions on the newly imported file

```
aspnet_regiis -pa "MyContainer" "MyDomain\My.Colleague"
aspnet_regiis -pa "MyContainer" "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
```

Next, I created a very simple web.config on my local machine.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="SecretKey" value="ValueWeWantToHide" />
    </appSettings>
    <configProtectedData>
        <providers>
            <add name="SampleProvider"
                 type="System.Configuration.RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL"
                 keyContainerName="MyContainer"
                 useMachineContainer="true" />
        </providers>
    </configProtectedData>
</configuration>
```

I can quite easily encrypt & decrypt the appSettings section here using the commands. They encrypt & decrypt successfully and the encrypted section is marked withe correct provider after encryption (`<appSettings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">`)

```
aspnet_regiis -pef appSettings D:\testapp
and
aspnet_regiis -pdf appSettings D:\testapp
```

However when I copy the encrypted web.config to my colleagues PC, and attempt to decrypt it with the command above, the decryption fails. It gives a very unhelpful error

```
Failed to decrypt using provider 'RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider'. Error message from provider: Bad Data
```

And now I'm stuck. I've found a couple of similar issues on SO but nothing concrete that specifically solved their problems. Have I missed a step somewhere. I assume *my* key setup is valid since I can locally encrypt/decrypt. Is it possible I've cocked-up the key import or missed some step on my colleagues machine. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you exported/imported both the public _and_ private keys?

Comment: Yes. There's actually a typo in my post which I'll fix now but I ran the export command with the -pri switch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are encrypting/decripting using the *default* provider on your machine (this will be different for each machine).

You need to specify the provider:

```
aspnet_regiis -pef appSettings D:\testapp -prov "SampleProvider"
```

On your colleagues machine:

```
aspnet_regiis -pdf appSettings D:\testapp
```

Comment: *facepalm* Thank you. I naively presumed that it would automatically use the KeyContainer specified in the Web.Config and didn't pay any attention to the "Provider Name" right beside it.

Comment: @EoinCampbell - It's one of those mistakes you have to make a few times before it sinks in ;)